# Python how to get element from json file that has multple elements in list

Tags: python, json, pyqt5

I have two drop down lists in pyqt5 One for the Material, and the other that has numbers from 0 - 3 what I want to happen is when I select the Material drop down and select **Hard Wood** and on the number drop down I have the number **2** selected for example what I want the output to be is:

```
['Hard Wood', '0.015 - 0.018']
```

json file:

```
        {
        "bits": [
            {
                "material": [
                    "Hard Wood"
                ],
                "chipload": [
                    "0.003 - 0.005", "0.009 - 0.011", "0.015 - 0.018", "0.019 - 0.021"
                ],
                "feedrate": [
                    "1 - 2", "3 - 4", "5 - 6", "7 - 8"
                ]
            },
        {
                "material": [
                    "Softwood & Plywood"
                ],
                "chipload": [
                    "0.004 - 0.006", "0.011 - 0.013", "0.017 - 0.020", "0.021 - 0.023"
                ],
                "feedrate": [
                    "1 - 2", "3 - 4", "5 - 6", "7 - 8"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Another example, lets say I want the **Softwood & Plywood** and on 0-3 drop down I select **1** I expect the output to be

```
['Softwood & Plywood', '0.011 - 0.013']
```

I have tried this code:

```py
    def SelectionFunction(self, text):
        for i, n in enumerate(materials):
            if text == materials[i]:
                self.selected_chipload = chiploads[self.bitWidthType.currentIndex()]
                self.selected_feedrate = feedrates[self.bitWidthType.currentIndex()]
                self.selected_material = materials[i]
```

But it doesn't work the way I want to.
(sorry if the variables are a bit confusing to you)
The material selection works, but what I can't figure out is how to make the 1-4 drop down select from where the Material drop down is.

Full Code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QComboBox, QDateTimeEdit,
        QDial, QDialog, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,
        QProgressBar, QPushButton, QRadioButton, QScrollBar, QSizePolicy,
        QSlider, QSpinBox, QStyleFactory, QTableWidget, QTabWidget, QTextEdit,
        QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPalette, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt, pyqtSignal, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys
import json
import tempfile
import os
canvas_height=220
canvas_width=300
file_dir = tempfile.gettempdir() + '\Bits\\'
if not os.path.exists(file_dir):
    os.makedirs(file_dir)
if not os.path.exists(file_dir + 'configure.json'):
    file = open(file_dir + 'configure.json', 'w+')
    file.write('''{
    \"bits\": [

    ]
}''')
    file.close()
with open(file_dir + 'configure.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
current_data = data
materials = []
bit_widths = ['1/8',
              '1/4',
              '3/8',
              '1/2']
chiploads = []
feedrates = []
if not materials:
    for bits in data['bits']:
        for material in bits['material']:
            materials.append(material)
        for chipload in bits['chipload']:
            chiploads.append(chipload)
        for feedrate in bits['feedrate']:
            feedrates.append(feedrate)
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.materialType = QComboBox(self)
        self.bitWidthType = QComboBox(self)
        self.selected_material = materials[0]
        self.selected_chipload = chiploads[0]
        self.selected_feedrate = feedrates[0]
        self.title = 'Bits'
        self.left = 100
        self.top = 100
        self.width = canvas_width
        self.height = canvas_height
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        # self.update_text()
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)

        # materialType BOX
        for i in materials:
            self.materialType.addItem(i)
        self.materialType.activated[str].connect(self.SelectionFunction) 
        self.materialType.setToolTip('Selection of materials')
        self.materialType.move(70, 20)

        # materialType BOX
        for i in bit_widths:
            self.bitWidthType.addItem(i + '"')
        self.bitWidthType.activated[str].connect(self.SelectionFunction) 
        self.bitWidthType.setToolTip('Selection of bit widths')
        self.bitWidthType.move(70, 50)

        self.show()
    def SelectionFunction(self, text):
        for i, n in enumerate(materials):
            if text == materials[i]:
                self.selected_chipload = chiploads[self.bitWidthType.currentIndex()]
                self.selected_feedrate = feedrates[self.bitWidthType.currentIndex()]
                self.selected_material = materials[i]
        print(self.selected_material, self.selected_chipload)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex=App()
    # camRun()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have the following curiosities: 1) I see that you print values corresponding to "material" and "chipload", are you also going to print to the corresponding value of "feedrate" ?, 2) If the answer of my previous question is affirmative then the number of "chipload" items is the same as "feedrate"?

Comment: Yes I will print the corresponding value of the feedrate, I just didn't mention it to avoid confusion. The code will still work
Yes they feedrate and chipload will always have the same length.

Thank you for these questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that both QComboBox are related, it is better to create a model where the roots are the items that the first QComboBox shows and the children of the roots are the items of the second QComboBox.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
├── configure.json
└── main.py
```

**main.py**

```py
import os
import json
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

ChiploadRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000
FeedrateRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1001


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.material_combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.bitwidth_combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()

        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.material_combobox.setModel(self.m_model)
        self.bitwidth_combobox.setModel(self.m_model)
        self.fill_model()

        self.material_combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(
            self._on_material_selection_changed
        )
        self.bitwidth_combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(
            self._on_bitwidth_selection_changed
        )
        self._on_material_selection_changed(self.material_combobox.currentIndex())

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.material_combobox)
        lay.addWidget(self.bitwidth_combobox)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def _on_material_selection_changed(self, index):
        root_index = self.m_model.index(index, 0)
        self.bitwidth_combobox.setRootModelIndex(root_index)
        self.bitwidth_combobox.setCurrentIndex(0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def _on_bitwidth_selection_changed(self, index):
        material = self.material_combobox.currentText()
        chipload = self.bitwidth_combobox.itemData(index, ChiploadRole)
        feedrate = self.bitwidth_combobox.itemData(index, FeedrateRole)

        print(material, chipload)  # , feedrate)

    def fill_model(self):
        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "configure.json")

        bit_widths = ["1/8", "1/4", "3/8", "1/2"]

        with open(filename) as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            bits = data["bits"]
            for e in bits:
                material_text = e["material"][0]
                root_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(material_text)
                self.m_model.appendRow(root_item)
                chipload_elements = e["chipload"]
                feedrate_elements = e["feedrate"]
                for text, chipload, feedrate in zip(
                    bit_widths, chipload_elements, feedrate_elements
                ):
                    it = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
                    it.setData(chipload, ChiploadRole)
                    it.setData(feedrate, FeedrateRole)
                    root_item.appendRow(it)


def main(args):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(args)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    ret = app.exec_()

    return ret


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: This works Like a charm! Thank you ever so much for this, I was so confused on how to do this but now its pretty clear to me, Thank you once again kind sir! Have a wonderful day. :)